# How do make for login and add to cart to checkout using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin, jmeter-3.2, ruby-jmeter

I'm new to JMeter. How do make for login and add to cart to checkout using jmeter? Can anybody tell me about bean shell for add to cart to checkout?

Answer (score 1):

1. Record your test scenario using your favorite web browser and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Perform **correlation** if required (detect and handle dynamic parameters)
3. Perform **parameterisation** if required (use external files/other sources to provide credentials and any other test data if required)
4. Validate your test (run it with 1 - 2 virtual users/loops and observe request and response in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener) to ensure that it does what it it supposed to be doing
5. [Add more virtual users](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#adding_users)
6. [Run your test in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
7. Analyze results using [JMeter HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

References:

- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [How to use JMeter for Login Authentication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421705-How-to-use-JMeter-for-Login-Authentication)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)